# Background-Image issus when user's screen smaller than holding wrapper

Tags: html, css

As the question states, in my website:

http://benjaminpotter.org/fleet/

I am struggling with getting the background issue to position properly when the user's browser size is smaller than 1000px (the wrapper)... is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the background image in the body directly, put it in a div, a bit like your wrapper.

With a margin:0 auto; style.

And nice website ;)